# Arrowing and circling a graph on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph

I would like to use an **arrow** to indicate a graph and put a comment. Also **circle** two curves and put a comment next to them.

Below is an example of arrow (black arrow) and circling (red circle) of a graph:

[image]

An example of a code to draw three (03) graph `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
A = [
      1.00       0.0579750 ;
      1.05       0.0485650 ;
      1.10       0.0403700 ;
      1.15       0.0298650 ;
      1.20       0.0250670 ;
      1.25       0.0202360 ;
      1.30       0.0149160 ;
      1.35       0.0083084 ;
      1.40       0.0049251 ;
      1.45       0.0027650 ;
      1.50       0.0015517 ;
      1.55       0.0010532 ;
      1.60       0.0004872 ;
      1.65       0.0002106 ;
      1.70       8.4448e-5 ;
      1.75       3.1525e-5 ;
      1.80       1.4776e-5 ;
      1.85       7.0152e-6 ;
      1.90       3.2969e-6 ;
      1.95       8.1243e-7 ;
      2.00       2.9669e-7 ;
     ];

B = [
      0.00       0.1205000 ;
      0.50       0.0898000 ;
      1.00       0.0629000 ;
      1.50       0.0387000 ;
      2.00       0.0146000 ;
      2.50       0.0034000 ;
      3.00       6.8762e-4 ;
      3.50       7.5193e-5 ;
      4.00       8.0134e-6 ;
      4.50       6.9000e-7 ;
      5.00       5.9005e-8 ;
      5.50       0.0000000 ;
      6.00       0.0000000 ;
     ];

C = [
      0.00       0.1368230 ;
      0.50       0.1091500 ;
      1.00       0.0814000 ;
      1.50       0.0413000 ;
      2.00       0.0198000 ;
      2.50       0.0077540 ;
      3.00       0.0018333 ;
      3.50       0.0005096 ;
      4.00       7.1185e-5 ;
      4.50       7.9925e-6 ;
      5.00       9.4009e-7 ;
      5.50       1.3001e-7 ;
      6.00       0.0000000 ;
     ];

semilogy(A(:,1),A(:,2),'ro-','LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',8)
hold on
semilogy(B(:,1),B(:,2),'bd-','LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',8)
semilogy(C(:,1),C(:,2),'r-+','LineWidth',1.5,'MarkerSize',8)

grid on

axis([1 6 1e-8 1e-1]);
A1 = 1 ; A2 = 0.5; A3 = 6;
xticks(A1: A2: A3);
Y = 10.^(-8: 1: -1);
yticks(Y);
set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')

xlabel('\textbf{ $\frac{\textbf{$E_{b}$}}{\textbf{$N_{0}$}}$ (dB)}','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold','color','k','Interpreter', 'Latex');

ylabel('\textbf{BER}\hspace*{1cm}','Rotation',90,'FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold','color','k','Interpreter', 'Latex');
```

The resulting graph:
[image]

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/annotating-graphs.html#AnnotatingPlotsExample-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the following line [from the examples](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/annotating-graphs.html#AnnotatingPlotsExample-3) and [the docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html#br2_upx-1-shapeType):

```
elps = annotation('ellipse',[.84 .68 .05 .05])
```

You will need to play with the location parameters to put it exactly where you want.

Comment: Thank you @Ander Biguri. I saw the different details from your link.